# AngularJS: for loop and nested if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to have something like the following HTML code using AngularJS:

```
<p class="itemsperpage">Items per page: <span>20</span> <span><a href="#">40</a></span> <span><a href="#">60</a></span> <span><a href="#">View all</a></span></p>
```

Where 20 is wrapped only by a , because is the current active element.

Now using AngularJS, how can I have something like:

```
var itemsPerPage = [20,40,60];
...
<p class="itemsperpage">Items per page:
    <span ng-repeat='i in itemsPerPage'>
        // here should print {{ i }} for the current active
        // <a href="#">{{ i }}</a> for the elements not active
    </span>
    <span><a href="#">View all</a></span>
</p>
```

Is it possible to do something like this using AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-if` like this:

```
<span ng-repeat='i in itemsPerPage'>
    <span ng-if="active === i">{{i}}</span>
    <a    ng-if="active !== i" href="#">{{i}}</a>
</span>
```

Simply keep the active item in `$scope.active`, for instance

```
$scope.active = 20;
```

Comment: This works even if will add an extra <span></span> inside the <span> that contains the ng-repeat.

Comment: If you really want to get rid of that you'd need a custom directive, so a more complex code. It is better it you can accomodate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `first` element would be active. Or for checking condition of 20, you could replace `$first` with `20`

**Markup**

```
<p class="itemsperpage">Items per page:
    <span ng-repeat='i in itemsPerPage'>
        <a href="#" ng-if="$first" ng-class="{active: $first }">{{ i }}</a> 
        <span href="#" ng-if="!$first">{{ i }}</span> 
    </span>
    <span><a href="#">View all</a></span>
</p>
```